# Calling variable from PHP Switch

Tags: php, sqlite

I can upload my document onto my main testing directory. But I wish to call out my variable which is staffNo and place it in the specific staffNo directory. But I'm not able to parse out the variable even though I have declared my appropriate name for my input.

For example:

**Staff Page**

```
$staffNo = 1;
<form id="Staff" name="Staff" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

//My staffno variable
<input type="hidden" id="staffNo" name="staffNo" value="<?php echo $staffNo ?>"/>

//Upload document
<input name="upload" id="upload" type="file"/>
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="upload"/>

//Submit button
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
switch($_POST['submit']) 
{
case 'Submit':
    if ($_FILES["upload"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["upload"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["upload"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["upload"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],
  "documents/"."staffNo"."/".$_FILES["upload"]["name"]);

            echo "Stored in: " ."./documents/"."staffNo"."/".  $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
}

break;

case 'others':
break;

default;
```

My staffNo variable was not able to call out even though it is under the form already. Did I did wrong somewhere? And I also wanted to create a new folder for the staffNo if it's not found inside. But now the basic staffNo variable was unable to call out. Kindly advise.

Comment: apply the gap <?php echo $staffNo?> TO <?php echo $staffNo ?>

Comment: @user976050 var_dump the $_POST['submit']

Comment: @user976050 what is this semicolon is for what???  <input name="upload" id="upload" type="file"/>"; <---
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="upload"/>";  <---- ???????

Comment: my mistake for that. But it doesn't affect the calling of variable anyway.

Comment: @user976050, Where is `$staffNo` defined?

Comment: @user976050 Can you please share the line that defines `$staffNo`?

Comment: @user976050 Never mind, I see you already have.

Comment: @user976050, okay, so *where* exactly is the problem then? Is it not echoing into your form, or not appearing in `upload.php`?

Comment: yeah. It keep saying undefined index. Unable to call out in my upload.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13547/discussion-between-spiritfyre-and-user976050)

Comment: Do you want to upload file in static directory staffNo or do you want to create directory dynamically each time when user upload file?

Comment: if the staffno folder is not exist inside my directory, i wan to create the directory dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed several errors in upload.php you have submitted.
You need to assign value of the hidden field to a variable:
`$staffNo = $_POST['staffNo'];`

upload.php

```
switch($_POST['submit']) 
{
    case 'Submit':
        if ($_FILES["upload"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["upload"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            $staffNo = $_POST['staffNo']; // preform validation here
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["upload"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["upload"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];
            // check if directory exists
            if(!is_dir("documents/".$staffNo)){
                // if it doesn't - create it
                mkdir("documents/".$staffNo);
            }
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],
            "documents/".$staffNo."/".$_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " ."./documents/".$staffNo."/".  $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
        }

    break;

    case 'others':
    break;

    default;
}
```

You should probably validate `staffNo` to prevent changing its value through firebug for example, and messing with the upload path.